# error:Property 'select' does not exist on type HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image: no error local demo]

[image: vscode complains error]

```
 function copy(){
        var Url=document.getElementById("Id");
        Url.select(); //error
        document.execCommand("Copy"); // browser copy
        }
```

as above. I'm trying to make a function to copy text in browser.but the error as title occurred
in typescript.
the select() is valid I think([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)),since I can copy correctly when I use it in a demo.
my ts version is 2.8.1

Comment: what type of element is the element you are trying to select the text from

Comment: `select` is not an `HTMLElement` method, it's a part of the [`Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) API

Comment: it's an Input element.but it copied correctly even the vscode complains about the error.
  <!-- The text field -->
  <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="Id">
  <!-- The button used to copy the text -->
  <button onclick="copy()">Copy text</button>

Comment: yeah，I also think select is not an HTMLElement method.but why the selecting works

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to add a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html):

```
var Url = document.getElementById("Id") as HTMLInputElement;
Url.select(); // OK
```

## Reason

`getElementById` can return any `HTMLElement`s. In your case *you know its an input* element so you can tell TypeScript that by using a type assertion .

Comment: awesome, so why the demo works correctly even I checked there is no select method on copyText. did the method exit on it's prototype chain?

Comment: yeah,I got it. HTMLInputElement has the select method.thanks

Comment: Similar issue I was trying to typecast with <HTMLInputElement> but it was throwing another error and came across this post.... A lifesaver!!!

Answer (score 6):

`select` method is defined for [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)s. The following will get rid of the TypeScript error.

```
let Url: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("Id") as HTMLInputElement;
Url.select();
document.execCommand("Copy");
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. If you look at the accepted answer edited link, that has been copied from this answer. So this is the first correct answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct type of the element, because React thinks it's just an HTMLElement instead of HTMLInputElement.

So, change to it!

var Url=document.getElementById("Id") as HTMLInputElement;